# How to Search from the root of Active Directory in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap

I'm attempting to use the Coldfusion Login Wizard to query Active Directory, however I'm having a problem with the directory structure.  Essentially, I need to query from multiple nested OUs that are under the same root OU.  So for instance, the OU "Admin" and "Staff" are children of the OU "School Users".  I'm able to use the following code to successfully query each sub OU individully, but I can't query the root (School Users) OU.

```
<!-- This is the include file that sets the attributes and collects the username and password passed by the user-->
<cfset args.authtype = "LDAP">
<cfset args.server = "ads.schoolname.org">
<cfset args.port = "389">
<cfset args.start = "dc=schoolname, dc=org">
<cfset args.suser = "usr">
<cfset args.spwd = "password">
<cfset args.queryString = "cn={username},OU=ADMIN,OU=SCHOOL USERS,DC=SCHOOLNAME,DC=ORG">

<!-- The following is a snippet of the authenticate file that takes the above info and attempts to query and authenticate the user -->

<cffunction name="ldapauth" access="private" output="true" returntype="struct" hint="Authenticate against a LDAP server." >
      <cfargument name="lServer" required="true" hint="The LDAP server."> 
      <cfargument name="lPort" hint="The port the LDAP server is running on.">
      <cfargument name="sUsername" required="true" hint="The username that was set in the Login Wizard.">
      <cfargument name="sPassword" required="true" hint="The password that was set in the Login Wizard.">
      <cfargument name="uUsername" required="true" hint="The username that was passed in from the client.">
      <cfargument name="uPassword" required="true" hint="The password that was passwd in from the client.">
      <cfargument name="sQueryString" required="true" hint="The string to be passed to the LDAP server">
      <cfargument name="lStart" required="true">


   <cfset var retargs = StructNew()>
      <cfset var username = replace(sQueryString,"{username}",uUserName)>

      <cfldap action="QUERY"
          name="userSearch"
          attributes="dn"
          start="#arguments.lStart#"
          server="#arguments.lServer#"
          port="#arguments.lPort#"
          username="#arguments.sUsername#"
          password="#arguments.sPassword#"  > 

    <!--- If user search failed or returns 0 rows abort --->
    <cfif  userSearch.recordCount EQ "" >
      <cfoutput>Error</cfoutput>
     </cfif>

    <!--- pass the user's DN and password to see if the user authenticates 
    and get the user's roles --->   

      <cfldap 
        action="QUERY"
        name="auth"
        attributes="dn,roles"
        start="#arguments.lStart#"
        server="#arguments.lServer#"
        port="#arguments.lPort#"
        username="#username#"
        password="#arguments.uPassword#" >

        <!--- If the LDAP query returned a record, the user is valid. --->
        <cfif auth.recordCount>
            <cfset retargs.authenticated="YES">
             <!--- return role here, default role is always "user" --->
            <cfset retargs.roles = "user">
        </cfif>               
    <cfreturn retargs>
  </cffunction>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the ColdFusion Login Wizard?

Comment: Macromedia Homesite+ 5.1 has the ability to automatically create a set of files for basic tasks such as connecting to an LDAP. This might be a newer version of that.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but query names ie userSearch need to be `var` scoped too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scope` attribute of `cfldap` and set it to `subtree`:
It will allow search from the start entry and all levels below it.

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work.  Here are the variables that are passed into cfldap <cfset args.authtype = "LDAP">
 <cfset args.server = "ads.hockaday.org">
 <cfset args.port = "389">
 <cfset args.start = "dc=hockaday, dc=org">
 <cfset args.suser = "setup">
 <cfset args.spwd = "lake99">
 <cfset args.queryString = "cn={username},OU=HOCKADAY USERS,DC=HOCKADAY,DC=ORG">

Comment: Up voting, since it sounds like your suggestion *was* part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to add the `scope` of subtree, but also change the way the username was being authenicated from CN=something to an email address with the domain